# Active Record: How to fetch data from 3 tables at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to fetch `sku_code` from `products`, `wh_name` from `warehouses` table and `item_count` from `product_warehouses`.

I tried something like

```
Product.all.includes(:product_warehouses)
```

But not working :(

Below are the schema of my tables

```
  create_table "product_warehouses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "warehouse_id"
    t.integer "item_count"
    t.integer "threshold"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_warehouses_on_product_id"
    t.index ["warehouse_id"], name: "index_product_warehouses_on_warehouse_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "sku_code"
    t.string "name"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "warehouses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "wh_code"
    t.string "wh_name"
    t.string "pin"
    t.integer "max_cap"
    t.integer "threshold"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Below are the relationship between tables:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_warehouses
  has_many :warehouses, through: :product_warehouses
end

class ProductWarehouse < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :warehouse
end

class Warehouse < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :product_warehouses
   has_many :products, through: :product_warehouses
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load all three records with a single query, use `eager_load`:

```
Product.all.eager_load(:product_warehouses, :warehouses)
```

Let's say you want to print sku_code, wh_name, and item_count in the console. First load all the products into variable:

```
products = Product.all.eager_load(:product_warehouses, :warehouses)
```

Then loop through the records and print out each of the values:

```
products.each do |product|
  puts "sku_code: #{product.sku_code}"

  product.product_warehouses.each do |product_warehouse|
    puts "item_count: #{product_warehouse.item_count}"
    puts "wh_code: #{product_warehouse.warehouse.wh_code}"
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good resource on the differences between joins, includes, eager_load, and preload: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: Thanks. But can you please explain how to fetch "sku_code" (products), "wh_name" (warehouses) and "item_count" (product_warehouses) after the eager loading you suggested.